# Find valid attributes for bokeh Themes

Tags: python, bokeh

I am e.g. wondering how to set `major_label_text_font_size` on a colorbar using a Theme, so I tried

```
theme = Theme(json={
'attrs' : {
    'Colorbar': {
        'major_label_text_font_size': '14pt',
    }
}})
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

How are these theme json or yaml files structured? Is there a recipe that tells me at which level of the nesting a given attribute such as `Colorbar` or `Figure` or `Title` should go?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ColorBar` ?

Comment: Thanks! Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: [bokeh.models.annotations](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.ColorBar)

Comment: Ok, fair enough if you know that it's the strings listed on that page that go into the Theme json at the level below `attr`. Still a bit confusing, but thanks.